# Excel keyboard shortcut behaving unexpectedly on Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

In excel the Cmd+Shift+Up keyboard shortcut will highlight from the current cell to the furthest non-empty cell above... ie. usually from the current cell to the top of the sheet.

This works fine for me except when I'm trying to use it while in the middle of editing a formula.  For example, if I'm trying to do an `=sum()` this is what happens:

1. I start typing `=sum(`
2. I arrow up to the cell above where the formula is being entered
3. I now want to select from the current cell upwards, but when I try and use my Cmd+Shift+Up keyboard shortcut, it changes to the next workbook!

How can I stop the behavior from changing to the next workbook while I'm editing a formula?

Comment: try to use .. Cmd + Up .. does it work?

Comment: @p._phidot_ Doing that will take me to the top of the sheet, but it won't highlight the cells.  However, once I'm at the top of the sheet I can Cmd+Shift+Down and that will work without changing sheets.  So it's an extra step but at least I can use shortcuts again.  Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Glad it (somehow..) works  /(^_^)\